# How to type text in TextBox and then be able to press return to click on Button?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox

I have a TextBox and a button. In TextBox I want to type text and then be able to click enter and press my button. When I press button I can redirect to text box by using `button1.Focus();`

Now if I type text and press enter nothing happens. I can use tab to switch to a button, but I just wonder if I can just press enter instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Click!");
}

private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        button1_Click(textBox1, new EventArgs());
}
```

If you are using this in more than one place I'd recommend creating a user control containing the `TextBox` and the `Button` in order to encapsulate this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In the properties of your form, set the button as the value for the `AcceptButton` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a KeyPressed event to your textbox. Inside this event check if the key pressed is enter, and if it is, call the button's click event.

Answer (score 1):

I think this way is a quite clever routine for your problem. This procedure allows you to check for TAB press as well. It is by the way snipped directly from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey.aspx

You're right on by simply changing the Keys.Tab in the microsoft sample to Key.Enter. Remember that when this textbox is used in conjunction with AutoComplete routines, it could be convenient to instantiate it outside the constructor or in a constructor overload. Here is what the instantiation of the textbox look like:
*ReturnTextBox returntextbox = new ReturnTextBox();*

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();

        ReturnTextBox returntextbox = new ReturnTextBox();
        returntextbox.Text = "returntextbox";
        panel.Controls.Add(returntextbox);

        TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
        textBox1.Text = "Normal TextBox";
        panel.Controls.Add(textBox1);

        this.Controls.Add(panel);
    }
}

class ReturnTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.SelectedText = "    ";                
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
}
```